# Powershell Script is adding users to folder ACL but not applying the permissions

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to add a user to a folder ACL with certain permissions. The below code adds the user to the ACL but it is not granting Read permissions. The variable $User_Name is just the variable defining the user I would like to have read permissions. Any help with this would be great.

```
$ACL = Get-ACL -Path c:\test
$AccessRule = New-Object 
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($User_Name,"Read","Allow")
$ACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$ACL | Set-Acl -Path c:\test
```

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to say where this goes wrong..
It could have to do with the extra newlines you put after `New-Object`,
or the identityreference in `$User_Name` (is that `Domain\UserAccountName` ?),
or as I suspect, it could be because you don't specify values for inheritance and propagation on the new access rule.

Try:

```
    $folder = 'C:\test'
    # create a new access rule
    # see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule
    $rule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($User_Name, "Read", "None,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

    # get the current ACL of the folder
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $folder
    # add the new rule to the ACL
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    $acl | Set-Acl $folder
```

See: [InheritanceFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.inheritanceflags) and [PropagationFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.propagationflags)

<sup>P.S. For Administration it is better to set file permissions on Groups, not single users. That makes it all far easier to maintain</sup>

---

**Note:**

Instead of `AddAccessRule()`, you might prefer `SetAccessRule()`.

**AddAccessRule()**
This method will add this access rule to the ACL.
If a user has Modify permission and we use AddAccessRule() to create a new rule with Read permission the user will *still also have* Modify permissions.

**SetAccessRule()**
This method removes any existing access an *replaces that access* with the specified rule.
If a user has Modify permission and a new rule is created using SetAccessRule() specifying Read permission, that user will now only have Read permission.